# Telerik RadConfirm does not work for UserControls of asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am calling Telerik's RadConfirm from UserControl's Server side  on uncheck of asp.net CheckedChanged event. The UserControl is repeated multiple times in a asp.net web page

If it is unchecked, then I will throw error message as

```
radWindowManager.RadConfirm("Are you sure you want to clear controls?", "confirmCallBackFn", 300, 100, null, "");
```

If argument is true, then I will clear and disable all the relevant controls

When I click checkbox for  first UserControl's checkbox, it is firing for the last UserControl. All the time it is working for the last UserControl. Below is the script for it

```
function confirmCallBackFn(arg)
{
    if (arg == true)
    {
        $find('<%= FindControl("txtAmount").ClientID %>').disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the callback function name unique for each user control instance, otherwise the last instnace will override the others: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/details/using-dynamic-unique-names-for-javascript-functions.

```
radWindowManager.RadConfirm("Are you sure you want to clear controls?", 
     "confirmCallBackFn" + this.ClientID, 
      300, 100, null, "");
```

and

```
function confirmCallBackFn<%=this.ClientID%>(arg) {
```